# Group by minute and fill missing

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do you preform a GROUP BY minute statement in Postgres? I also wonder what if there is record missing how to replace missing with zero?

```
SELECT avg(load) as load, min(created_at) as create_at FROM stats GROUP BY ?what here?
```

So then I'll get rows like:

```
   created_at   | load
27.3.2013 16:08 | 15
27.3.2013 16:09 | 14
27.3.2013 16:10 | 16
27.3.2013 16:12 | 15
```

There is one record missing, notice

```
27.3.2013 16:11 | 0
```

How to set default values or how is this called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to join in a set containing all the minutes you need. You can use generate_series(start, stop, step) for this. Goes something like this:

```
SELECT avg(load), min(created_at) as load 
FROM generate_series('2013-3-20 0:00:00'::timestamp, '2013-3-30 0:00:00', 
              '1 minute') AS minutes(minute)
    LEFT JOIN stats ON minute=date_trunc('minute', stats.created_at)
GROUP BY minute
```

Comment: You need `minute=date_trunc('minute',stats.created_at)`, otherwise it wont join when `stats.created_at` has seconds.

Comment: @Eelke is it possible to get fill missing with where condition ?

Comment: @AnkitDoshi If you want to filter rows from the second table you need to put your condition in the ON condition of the LEFT JOIN not in the WHERE. `LEFT JOIN stats ON (minute=date_trunc('minute', stats.created_at) AND foo=bar)`

Comment: @Eelke Now i will post another question so please help me out if possible

Comment: @Eelke Please help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650877/group-by-minute-and-fill-missing-with-where