# group by minute and fill missing with where

Tags: postgresql

columns of table

```
date                |count|ip
2014-05-14 11:21:00 |2    | 222.222.222.22
2014-05-14 11:22:00 |4    | 232.232.232.23
2014-05-14 11:24:00 |1    | 222.222.222.22
```

[this is working fine for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667941/group-by-minute-and-fill-missing) but this solution give me value null for series but I need value 0 instead of null

In the current query I can't get exact sequence without where I get fill missing sequence

Current Query:

```
SELECT sum(date),minute
FROM generate_series('2014-05-14 0:00:00'::timestamp, '2014-05-14 23:59:59', 
              '1 minute') AS minutes(minute)
    LEFT JOIN table ON minute=date_trunc('minute',table.date) 
where switch_ip='232.232.232.23'
GROUP BY minute
```

Current Output :

```
2014-05-14 11:22:00 |4
```

Required Output :

1) If in where ip = 232.232.232.23 and date >= '2014-05-14 00:00:00' and date <= '2014-05-14 23:59:59'

```
2014-05-14 11:21:00 | 0
2014-05-14 11:22:00 | 4
2014-05-14 11:23:00 | 0
```

2) If in where ip 222.222.222.22 and date >= '2014-05-14 00:00:00' and date <= '2014-05-14 23:59:59'

```
2014-05-14 11:21:00 | 2
2014-05-14 11:22:00 | 0
2014-05-14 11:23:00 | 0    
2014-05-14 11:24:00 | 1
```

3)If in where date >= '2014-05-14 00:00:00' and date <= '2014-05-14 23:59:59'

```
2014-05-14 11:21:00 | 2
2014-05-14 11:22:00 | 4
2014-05-14 11:23:00 | 0    
2014-05-14 11:24:00 | 1
```

Comment: Could you add your actual query to the question? It's hard to modify a query without seeing it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Please reply me if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By placing the ip condition in the where clause you turned the outer join into an inner join. Move it to the join condition

```
select coalesce(sum("count"), 0), minute
from
    generate_series(
        '2014-05-14 0:00:00'::timestamp,
        '2014-05-14 23:59:59', 
        '1 minute'
    ) minutes(minute)
    left join
    t on
        minutes.minute = date_trunc('minute', t.date)
        and
        ip = '232.232.232.23'
group by minute
order by minute
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/31483/5

To have the timestamp as a comma separated string replace

```
select coalesce(sum("count"), 0), minute
```

by

```
select 
    coalesce(sum("count"), 0), 
    to_char(minute, 'YYYY,MM,DD,HH24,MI') as minute
```

Comment: "I need value 0 instead of null", so you may want to coalesce.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto is it possible to get result in comma seprated string like (0,4,0) of 1st query

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto will you please suggest me same query for mysql because i have tried to search but  every show me create a new table for missing dates

Comment: @Ankit In MySQL it is necessary to create a table for missing dates.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto exactly i found same solution but is it possible to do without create table because in my case i have to made query for report in which i get data minute base.Suppose current system time is 9:30:00 then i have data for 00:00:00 to 09:30:00 in database and for other data(9:31:00 to 23:59:00) i need query which is just give me count is 0 for all other data and after every minute i will get data from database so not possible to create table may be my descirption is not proper but i thought u can understand what i mean exactly

Comment: @Ankit There is no other solution in MySQL other than creating that table. Ask a question with the MySQL tag.